# Naive calculations with infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, divergent-series

In the realm, where the [sum of natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%E2%8B%AF) is $-1/12$ :

$1+2+3+4+...=-1/12$

Is this true?:

$2+4+6+8+...=2*(1+2+3+4+...)=-2/12$

Can this kind of naive calculations always be done? -or are there dangers lurking in the infinity?

Comment: I blame Numberphile and Phil Plait (Bad Astronomy) for this. This divergent series has been getting asked about here a few times a week for the past couple months...

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/